# Limitations of Qualtrics API

Tags: surveymonkey, qualtrics

With respect to the Qualtrics API (v3) documentation (https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/overview) there does not appear to be any means to send a GET request through a REST client to get the individual survey responses for a specific survey (I suppose that the developers figured that no would be interested in decoupling the survey results from the admin panel).

The reason why I would like to be able to submit a GET request to get survey results is for real-time data visualization purposes that do not depend on me exporting the data every so often to re-update the visualization. If Qualtrics does not support such a GET request, which service (perhaps SurveyMonkey or its ilk) best facilitates what I'm trying to build? Or do I have to build an entire survey module from scratch? (shudders)

Answer (score 3):

I agree that v3.0 has some big short comings.  I have no idea what they are thinking.  There should be a way to retrieve a specific response using Response ID.

You can still use v2.5 of the api to do what you want.

Comment: I wrote a followup post describing my attempts at using v2.5 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336685/incorrect-username-or-password-error-message-in-qualtrics-api-v2-5). If you have any idea of other ways to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: v2.5 works. I'll look at your other post and answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

SurveyMonkey has a REST API that allows you to fetch all your responses.

You can [fetch all your responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#survey-responses) by doing:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses
```

Which will give you a skinny payload (usually IDs only, and maybe a name or title but not in this case).

You can then [get a specific response](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#responses-id) by doing:

```
GET /v3/responses/<response_id>
```

You can also [fetch all responses as fatter payloads](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-bulk) by doing:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/bulk
```

Or, depending on your use case, for example if you have some visualization that you want to update in real-time without polling for responses you can [set up a webhook](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhooks).

```
POST /v3/webhooks
{
    "name": "My Response Webhook",
    "event_type": "response_completed",
    "object_type": "survey",
    "object_ids": ["<survey_id1>", "<survey_id2>", ...],
    "subscription_url": "https://mycallback.url"
}
```

Where `subscription_url` is your callback url, and then whenever any new responses for the defined surveys come in you'll be notified to the `subscription_url` provided and you can then know to refresh your charts.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that by getting contacts, in every contact there are object of Response history where you can get the information of a survey assigned to a respondents.