# "Incorrect username or password" error message in Qualtrics API v2.5

Tags: javascript, api, survey, surveymonkey, qualtrics

Due to some features that I wish were available in Qualtrics v3 ([see previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336311/limitations-of-qualtrics-api/37336392#37336392)), I checked out their most recent previous version ([v2.5](https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/docs.php)) to try to find a GET request which closely approximates the data from individual surveys that I'm trying to obtain on each request. However, when I do their built-in API test on my own credentials:

[image]

I get the following error:

```
<XML>
<Meta>
<Status>Error</Status>
<RequestType>getSurvey</RequestType>
<ErrorCode>500</ErrorCode>
<QualtricsErrorCode>ESRV09</QualtricsErrorCode>
<ErrorMessage>Incorrect Username or Password</ErrorMessage>
<Debug/>
</Meta>
<Result/>
```

I've double-checked to ensure that I'm entering the proper credentials, well-defined survey ID, and API token, but am not sure why I am getting this error.

As an aside, if there is another survey platform (such as SurveyMonkey) which has an API which allows me to extract information from individual surveyIDs without having to export everything manually first, I would greatly appreciate any knowledge of such services.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image above you are missing the URL field, which should be api.php. Also, I think you want response data, so the request would be getLegacyResponseData.

At a minimum, the actual generated url should be something like this:

https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php?API_SELECT=ControlPanel&Version=2.5&Request=getLegacyResponseData&User=[user_name_here]&Token=[token_here]&Format=JSON&SurveyID=[survey_id_here]

Answer (score 0):

You should not set JSONPCallback to false. Set it to true and to setup your Ajax call properly, refer to [JQuery JSONP documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)

Answer (score 0):

I called the Qualtrics customer support line when I was getting the same error. It turns out my organization changed the way that users get access to Qualtrics from individual accounts to using single sign on. When they did that my username changed! It used to me my organizational email address, but after the change it was different, although the API token was the same. In order to find your username:

1. log into the Qualtrics control panel
2. click on the user silhouette in the upper righthand corner and select "Account Settings..."
3. On the main User Settings page, scroll down to the section titled "Recent Logins"
4. Your username is listed in the leftmost column of that table

I was surprised that my username was NOT the email address that I used to get access to my account. Hope this helps someone!